# Convert json to csv for similar keys

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a `personID` and that person can have multiple `fileID`.

I need to write the `personID` as well as the multiple `fileID`s to a csv file. Note that the list can be long.

The json response I get back looks like this

```
[{'ID': 94263, 'Name': 'Police Check Certificate', 'Ref': '304189', 'ExpiryDate': '2021-07-25'}, {'ID': 94264, 'Name': 'Public Liability - Cert of Currency', 'Ref': 'CA-IS-001-3DWINDOWS', 'ExpiryDate': '2020-07-17'}, {'ID': 94265, 'Name': 'Workcover Cert of Currency', 'Ref': '12824546', 'ExpiryDate': '2020-06-30'}]
```

I need to convert this json response to csv with the id; something like the image attached below.[image]

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or a tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you should try to convert your json object to a list of dict.
then, you can convert your list to dataframe, and to csv.

```
import pandas as pd 
list_of_dict = [{'ID': 94263, 'Name': 'Police Check Certificate', 'Ref': '304189', 'ExpiryDate': '2021-07-25'}, {'ID': 94264, 'Name': 'Public Liability - Cert of Currency', 'Ref': 'CA-IS-001-3DWINDOWS', 'ExpiryDate': '2020-07-17'}, {'ID': 94265, 'Name': 'Workcover Cert of Currency', 'Ref': '12824546', 'ExpiryDate': '2020-06-30'}
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)
df["contractorID"] = 447
df.to_csv("json.csv")
```

Comment: thanks but how do I add the contractorID which is not in the initial json response I get back

Comment: just add a column named contractorID    df["contractorID"] = 447

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), which is easy enough to install if you don't already have access to it.  However, jq expects its input to be valid JSON, so you would need to convert the quasi-JSON shown in the example to valid JSON.  There are many ways to do that, but a simple option would be to use a command-line program such as [hjson](/questions/tagged/hjson).

Once you have the JSON, you could proceed along the following lines:

- if the keys are all already in the required order:

  jq -r '.[] | [447] + [.[]] | @csv'
- otherwise:

  jq -r '.[] | [447, .ID, .Name, .Ref, .ExpiryDate] | @csv'

You could either pipe the JSON into jq (e.g. from hjson), or give the file name on the command-line.